# ruby on rails: undefined stringify_keys

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, nested

I'm learning to render forms from different controllers, but when I try to save data, it says that I get

```
NoMethodError in ProfilesController#create
undefined method `stringify_keys' for "2":String
```

My **routes** file:

```
resources :users do
  member do
   get 'profile'
  end
end
```

**Profile model**

```
belongs_to :user
```

**User model**

```
has_one :profile
```

**views/profiles/_form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for [@user, @profile] do |f| %>
  ..
<% end %>
```

**views/users/_form.html.erb**

```
<%= render :partial => "profiles/form" %>
```

Also, to mention, when I tried to save the data, I get redirected to `http://localhost:3000/users/2/profiles` where the error occurs, instead of `http://localhost:3000/users/2/profile`
**notice the `s` in profile**, it changes on me?

Thanks!

Comment: It's indicating that you have a nested resources route for profiles, but that's not showing in your routes. Have you posted the entire contents of your routes.rb?

Comment: In my experience every time I get the stringify keys error it has to do with a hash I'm passing into a method being constructed improperly.

Comment: @andrewliu, if you are rendering a partial from a partial, you should probably think about refactoring your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would take a slightly different approach. Rather than adding a GET member route for `profile` to the users resources route, I would nest a resource route for profile *within* your users route.

```
# config/routes.rb
resources :users do
    resource :profiles // notice the singular resource
end
```

This will provide the routes you need to RESTfully route to the nested profile resource.

Then you can create a form precisely as you've indicated:

```
# app/views/profiles/_form.html.erb
<%= form_for [@user, @profile] do |f| %>
    ...
<% end %>
```

In your `ProfilesController`, you can access the user in the following fashion:

```
# app/controllers/profiles_controller.rb
user = User.find(params[:user_id])
profile = user.profile
```

I'm not certain whether this *will* definitely resolve the error message you're receiving, but it very well *might*.

EDIT:

Regarding the comment below mentioning `undefined method 'model_name' for NilClass:Class` in your form: you're receiving this error because no variables are being passed to your partial scope. When rendering a partial, you need to pass in whatever local variables you'd like the partial to have access to:

```
# app/views/users/_form.html.erb
<%= render :partial => "profiles/form", :locals => {:user => @user, :profile => @profile} %>
```

Be cognizant, however, that the variables you pass to partial will only be accessible as *local* variables, not instance ones:

```
# app/views/profiles/_form.html.erb
<%= form_for [user, profile] do |f| %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

Comment: in which action do I put that code: `user = User.find(params[:user_id])`?

Comment: Doesn't matter. Presumably, you are in either your `new` or `update` actions, but in either scenario, you'll be able to access `user_id` via `params[:user_id]`.

Comment: I get undefined method 'profiles' in my index action. I have this in it `@user = User.find(params[:user_id])` and `@profiles = @user.profiles`

Comment: Because `User` `has_one` `Profile`, you should use the singular of "profiles" when doing this lookup, i.e., `@user.profile`. I've amended my answer above to show an example.

Comment: ahh good catch! but darn! I'm getting this error now: `undefined method 'model_name' for NilClass:Class` and its referring to the form in my views page, any idea what that is about? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Please post the relevant controllers and views in their entirety. I suspect you are not passing your instance variables to your view partials, but it's difficult to definitely know unless we can see some code.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31905/discussion-between-zeantsoi-and-andrewliu)